# How to translate a currency number to french words in RTF template BI publisher?

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

How to translate a currency number to french words in RTF template BI publisher?

Input:

```
   <AMOUNTS>
   <VALUE>123.56</VALUE>
   </AMOUNTS>
```

Required Output: cent vingt-trois dollars et cinquante cents

I searched for inbuilt functions but couldnt see any information. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Is this in a printed check?

Comment: Yes. The output will be a PDF document with Check stub. I need to convert the currency number into french language words

Comment: Are you using EBS r12? The payment process should allow for printing in French, and the payment amount as text should come through as French in the data definition XML file processed by BI Publisher. As far as I remember, you can't do the amount to text in BI publisher. There's some pretty complicated stuff that happens in the PL/SQL to get stuff with the correct grammar.

Comment: Thanks! I will only get amount in XML. I have to convert it from here.

Comment: If you are using the out of the box functionality, it should to all the work for you. When I worked on the check printing for Mexico, the checks came out in Spanish without any custom work for language translations.